# What are the differences between weapons?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

For example, I believe that with sub-machine guns you can move faster while aiming down sight. Are there any other differences like this either between weapon types or between weapons within the same type?

Also, do the damage, accuracy, etc. meters between the different weapon types match up? Is 5 bars of damage for an Assault Rifle the same as 5 bars of damage for an LMG?

The reason that I bring this up is that I've been a fairly below average player, but the other night I created a new class with the Galil. Maybe it's my imagination, but it seems like the kick on it is much less than other weapons (including other Assault Rifles). I've been dominating since then. Maybe something just clicked in my play or I've been lucky in server placement, but like I said it seems like the gun is more accurate and I have a much better KDR than even the AK47 or AK74u.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of differences with the weapons, similar to what you have noticed.  With an LMG you move the slowest and with a SMG, as you noticed, you move the fastest.  Recoil, stopping power, rate of fire, and accuracy in both ADS and hip firing vary from weapon to weapon as well.

And yes, the bars generally match up exactly from weapon class to class.

The Galil is one of the best weapons in the game with good stopping power, a steady rate of fire, and good accuracy.  I also found it to be one of the best Assault Rifles in the game myself.

If you want actual values I recommend going to the [Black Ops Weapons Page](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Call_of_Duty:_Black_Ops_Weapons) on Call of Duty Wiki at Wikia as that seems to be the best place I've found for info on the weapons.  There is a ton of information there that may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a wide variety of differences between weapons, even within the same group. [This page](http://denkirson.xanga.com/735016527/black-ops/) gives a highly detailed breakdown of the differences between each weapon.

As you noted, the characteristics of even the same type of weapon differ. Each assault rifle, for example, has a different amount of recoil and even a different recoil "style" (i.e., some climb up, some kick up and to the right, etc.). Weapons in the same group even have different attachment options.

In terms of differences between groups, as you noticed, SMGs are "faster" than assault rifles, which are "faster" than LMGs. This means that (a) you move faster with an SMG, (b) you pop into ADS faster with SMGs, and (c) SMGs are faster to switch to than assault rifles (ditto for assault rifles vs. LMGs).

Sniper rifles are almost in a class by themselves. It takes a moderate amount of time to switch to/from a sniper rifle, and popping into ADS with sniper rifles is slow. You can hold your breath while aiming with a sniper rifle, though.